# How to skip document using mongoose?

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

Hi I am using mongoose nodejs express and angular. I have the api from which i get all users details stored in database but I want to skip the user details who logged in or registered . How can I skip the particular user detail. Please help me to solve this.I'm new to angular so please help me to get use to angular and solve the problems.

here is my api.js

```js
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
    } 
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
    if ( token === 'null') {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request') 
    }
    let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey')
    if (!payload) {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request') 
    }
    req.userId = payload.subject
    next()
}

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('From API routes')
})

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    let userData =
     req.body
    let user = new User(userData)
    user.save((error, registerdUser) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            let payload = { subject: registerdUser._id}
            let token = jwt.sign(payload, 'secretKey')
            res.status(200).send({token})
        }
    })
})

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let userData = req.body
    User.findOne({username: userData.username}, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
             console.log(error)
        } else {
            if (!user) {
                res.status(401).send('Invalid username')
            } else
            if ( user.password !== userData.password) {
                res.status(401).send('Invalid password')  
            } else {
                let payload = { subject: user._id}
                let token = jwt.sign(payload,'secretKey')
                res.status(200).send({token})
            }
        }
    })
})

router.get('/menu', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    let userData = req.body 
})

router.post('/doner',  (req, res) => {
    User.find({}, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
             console.log(error)
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(user)
        }
    })
})

router.post('/search',  (req, res) => {
    let userData = req.body
    User.find({bloodgroup: userData.bloodgroup}, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
             console.log(error)
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(user)
        }
    })
})

router.post('/forgotPswrd', (req, res) => {
    let userData =req.body
    User.findOne({email: userData.email}, (error,user) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
       } else 
           if (!user) {
               res.status(401).send('Email Does not exists')
           } else {
           res.status(200).send(user._id)
           }
       })
})

router.post('/reset', (req,res) => {
    let userData= req.body

   User.updateOne({_id: user._id, $set: {password: userData.password}}, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
       } else {
          
           res.status(401).send(user)
       }
       })
})
```

```html
router.post('/doner',  (req, res) => {
    User.find({}, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
             console.log(error)
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(user)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi there! Is there a way to know the `_id`(or any unique identifier) of the user that is currently logged-in in the `POST /doner` request handler?

Comment: i have inserted my api.js .now you can see

Comment: By finding the all the users apart from the one that's logged in using `$ne` operator.
`Users.find({  _id: { $ne: IdOfLoggedUser }}, callback)` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/

Comment: How can i pass the loggedin user id to this post request

Comment: The `verifyToken` middleware should help with passing the logged-in user id to the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `verifyToken` middleware to authenticate the request after which the `userId` would be stored in the `req` object.

For the database query, use the [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/index.html) query operator to select all users whose id is not that of the current logged in user.

```
router.post('/doner', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  // Extract the `userId` from the req object
  const userId = req.userId;
  User.find({ $ne: userId }, (error, user) => {
      if (error) {
           console.log(error);
      } else {
          res.status(200).send(user);
      }
  });
});
```